# Make a frameless QWindow movable

Tags: qt

I'm working with the QWindow object in Qt.
Once the frameless flag is set, the window becomes fixed to its default location. 
Is there anyway to get back the movability that was lost when this flag was set.  I've tried a couple different ways but they all require the move() function that seems to only be for QWidget objects

Comment: So use [`QWindow::setPosition`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#setPosition) instead?

Comment: By movability you mean, moving by mouse when it has `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`? Do you realize that it might be OS dependant? On Linux we have this movability by pressing LAlt + LMB. On Windows it will be different story. Or maybe you could catch some mouse events and handle it by your self somehow, but on first glance it seems to me overcomplicated.

Comment: Thanks thuga. I figured out how to move the window using setPosition along with mousePress and mouseMove events but when I try using mouseRelease no event is caught.  Still need to try a few other things but thanks again for the tip

Comment: I think the mouse release event is only caught if the cursor is on that same widget when the button is released. If the cursor is outside of the widget, or if there is some other widget that eats that event on top of it, your widget won't get that event.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from `QWidget` and override `mouseMoveEvent`, `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`. Keep track of the distance from the topleft (center or whatever) to the cursor when a mouse button is pressed; move it when the mouse if moved, if the button is still pressed.

I would do it by adding a `bool tracking` member variable and a `QPoint delta` variable to keep track of when to move the window and how far.

You can use this to add custom styleable titlebars; inherit from QWidget and add all the trimming as describe above and let it move it's farthest ancestor (parent or parents parent, as long it's not null).